# Movement code for a game that should be able to handle almost infinite coordinates

Tags: python, performance, floating-point, coordinate-system

Now I've grasped the very basics of Pygame, I thought it'd be useful to make a few classes that I could use later on if I try make a simple RPG style game. I've done this to handle the coordinates for the player movement (and possibly for other things too), and tried to do it in a way where you wouldn't get the floating point precision errors that Minecraft and similar games get when you travel out very far.

I tested it against the `decimal` module, and mine appeared to up to 10x faster for small movements, though the speeds evened out when using super large movements like +- 10000000000000.

It's only half a days worth of work so it's not perfect, I can't find any more bugs though. It's recommended you input the coordinates as strings though if you're using large ones to start with, especially if you're using floats.

```
class Movement(object):
    """This was built to allow large coordinates to be stored without
    causing any floating point precision errors.
    It is faster than the decimal module, especially with processing
    large amounts of small movements.

    It works by breaking down the coordinates into 'blocks', where each
    new block is the squared amount of the previous one.
    The method is very similar to the base number system, in which a
    block size of 10 will split 235.9 into [5.9, 3, 2].

    A large block size is faster than a small one, though the precision
    will be worse. At 16 digits, Python can't store any more decimals,
    so definitely keep it under that.
    """

    BLOCK_SIZE = 65535
    COORDINATES = range(3)

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0, block_size=None):
        """Convert the starting coordinates into the format accepted
        by the class.

        >>> m = Movement('15',
        ...              '-31564.99933425584842',
        ...              '1699446367870005.2')
        >>> m.player_loc
        [[15.0], [-31564.99933425585], [38640.2, 17514, 2485, 6]]

        >>> print m
        (15.0, -31564.9993343, 1699446367870005.2)
        """

        #Set a new block size if needed
        if block_size is not None:
            self.BLOCK_SIZE = block_size

        #Store the initial coordinates
        self.player_loc = [self.calculate(self._get_integer(i),
                                          self._get_decimal(i))
                           for i in map(str, (x, y, z))]


    def __repr__(self):
        """This needs improving, currently it just converts back to
        the absolute coordinates."""
        return 'Movement({}, {}, {})'.format(*self._convert_to_world())


    def __str__(self):
        """Print the absolute coordinates."""
        return str(tuple(self._convert_to_world())).replace("'", "")


    def __getitem__(self, i):
        """Return an absolute value for X, Y or Z.

        Parameters:
            i (int): Index of coordinate.
        """
        try:
            return self._convert_to_world()[i]
        except IndexError:
            MovementError.index_error_coordinate()


    def __setitem__(self, i, n):
        """Set an absolute value for X, Y or Z.

        Parameters:
            i (int): Index of coordinate.

            n (int/float): New value to set.
        """
        n = str(n)
        try:
            self.player_loc[i] = self.calculate(self._get_integer(n),
                                                self._get_decimal(n))
        except IndexError:
            MovementError.index_error_coordinate()


    @classmethod
    def _get_integer(self, n):
        """Convert the input to an integer.

        Parameters:
            n (str): Integer to convert.

        >>> Movement._get_integer('15.35321')
        15
        """
        return int(n) if '.' not in n else int(n.split('.')[0])


    @classmethod
    def _get_decimal(self, n):
        """Get the decimal number from the input.

        Parameters:
            n (str): Decimal to convert.

        >>> Movement._get_decimal('15.35321')
        35321
        """
        return 0 if '.' not in n else int(n.split('.')[1])


    def calculate(self, amount, decimal=0):
        """Convert the coordinate into a block.

        Parameters:
            amount (int/str): Total value without any decimals.

            decimal (int, optional): The decimal value as an integer
                without the leading '0.'.

        >>> Movement().calculate(128)
        [128.0]
        >>> Movement().calculate(128, 5176)
        [128.5176]
        >>> Movement().calculate(4294836224)
        [65534.0, 65534]
        >>> Movement().calculate(4294836225)
        [0.0, 0, 1]
        """
        coordinate = []
        amount = int(amount)
        negative = amount < 0
        multiplier = int('-1'[not negative:])

        if negative:
            amount *= -1

        while amount > self.BLOCK_SIZE - 1:
            remainder = amount % self.BLOCK_SIZE
            amount = (amount - remainder) / self.BLOCK_SIZE
            coordinate.append(int(remainder * multiplier))
        coordinate.append(int(amount * multiplier))

        decimal = float('0.' + str(int(decimal)))
        coordinate[0] += decimal * int('-1'[not coordinate[0] < 0:])

        return coordinate


    def _move(self, direction, amount, final_run=False):
        """Add the coordinate to a block.

        Parameters:
            direction (int): Represents X, Y, or Z as a number.

            amount (int/float): Amount to add or subtract from the
            coordinate.

        >>> m = Movement(135, 426.42, -1499941.5002)
        >>> print m
        (135.0, 426.42, -1499941.5002)

        >>> m.move(100, -5133.100532, 5)
        >>> print m
        (235.0, -4706.680532, -1499936.5002)
        """

        #Fix to keep decimals on large numbers
        if not final_run and amount > self.BLOCK_SIZE:
            decimal = self.player_loc[direction][0] % 1
            if '.' in str(amount):
                decimal += float('0.' + str(amount).split('.')[1])
            self.player_loc[direction][0] += int(amount)
        else:
            self.player_loc[direction][0] += amount

        #Recalculate and add blocks if needed
        i = 0
        while i < len(self.player_loc[direction]):

            stop = True
            current_block = self.player_loc[direction][i]
            while not -self.BLOCK_SIZE < current_block < self.BLOCK_SIZE:
                stop = False

                remainder = current_block % self.BLOCK_SIZE
                new_addition = int(current_block - remainder) / self.BLOCK_SIZE
                if i:
                    remainder = int(remainder)
                self.player_loc[direction][i] = remainder

                try:
                    self.player_loc[direction][i + 1] += new_addition
                except IndexError:
                    self.player_loc[direction].append(new_addition)

            #Break execution if higher blocks are not edited
            if stop:
                break

            i += 1

        #Add the final decimals if a large number was input
        try:
            self._move(direction, decimal, final_run=True)
        except UnboundLocalError:
            pass


    def move(self, x, y, z):
        """Update the coordinates with a new relative location."""
        for i, amount in enumerate((x, y, z)):
            if amount:
                self._move(i, amount)


    def _convert_to_world(self):
        """Convert the blocks into absolute coordinates as a string."""

        #Convert coordinates back to numbers, without using floats
        coordinates = [sum(int(amount) * pow(self.BLOCK_SIZE, i)
                           for i, amount in enumerate(coordinate))
                       for coordinate in self.player_loc]

        #Add the decimal points as strings
        coordinates = [(str(coordinates[i])
                        + '.'
                        + str(float(self.player_loc[i][0])).split('.')[1])
                       for i in self.COORDINATES]

        #Fix for numbers between -1 and 0
        for i in self.COORDINATES:
            if (len(self.player_loc[i]) == 1
                and str(self.player_loc[i][0]).startswith('-0.')):
                coordinates[i] = '-' + coordinates[i]
        return coordinates


class MovementError(Exception):
    """Custom movement exceptions."""
    @classmethod
    def index_error_coordinate(self):
        raise MovementError('coordinate index out of range')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

In response to the comment by holroy, I decided to keep with float (as opposed to store the decimal value as a separate int) because I've still got to think about conversion to and from the game world. With the current way, unless the float value goes above the block size, it's literally just a single addition, whereas the other way would be a lot slower, and the precision to that level isn't really needed.

I did the block method in a previous project which was about octrees, where the coordinates were stored relative to each 3D block, which was split into 8 smaller blocks (so a coordinate would be `[(1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, 1)]` for 4 nested blocks, which results in `(5, 13, 11)`. The problem with this approach is if a coordinate was at 16, that's too high to store, so you'd need to recalculate everything for 5 blocks instead of 4 (which upon writing this, I've realised it may be as simple as multiplying all of block 4 by -1, though I'm not sure).

The boundaries can also be a bit confusing, as the size of the block is `-(2^x)+1` to `2^x`, like -255 to 256.

I wanted this to be able to scale as much as needed, without getting overly complicated, and the current way seems to accomplish this fine.

Comment: Since python supports seemingly arbitrarily large integers, why do you use decimals with limited precision at all? If  you want to have block coordinates and coordinates with in the block, then why not make the coordinate a tuple of (block, sub-block coordinate), where both values are integers?

Comment: What I really are aiming at, is could you explain a little more why you have chosen this design on how to handle the coordinates?

Comment: Updated the question with some of the points you mentioned, I'm never great at wording stuff so let me know if some parts need to be clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## _get_integer and _get_decimal

A lot to say here. First, you’ve got a bug. Consider `float('.0')` and `float('3.')` which are valid calls that anyone may expect to work alike with your `Movement` class. Unfortunately, both `Movement('.0')` and `Movement('3.')` fails. This is due to an empty string being returned as one part or the other of the `split('.')`. And `int('')` is not valid.

An other thing to note, here, is that both functions will always be called together. And that they both convert the same argument into a string to split it right after. It’s redundant. Better have only one function that will split the string and return both the integral *and* the decimal part as a tuple. Moreover, it’ll be easier to fix the bug stated above:

```
def split_decimal_part(number):
    n = str(number)
    try:
        integral, decimal = n.split('.')
    except ValueError: # no '.' in `n`
        return int(n), 0
    else:
        # Account for either integral or decimal being ''
        return int(integral) if integral else 0, int(decimal) if decimal else 0
```

Last and not least: do not confuse yourself between [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#classmethod) and [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#staticmethod). Class methods are implicitly passed the class instance as first parameter (usualy named `cls`) and not `self` which is an instance of the class. Static methods does not have implicit parameters at all. They just use the class or the instance type as a namespace. Since you make no use of the class parameter of your `@classmethod`s, they should be `@staticmethod`s instead.

## On `@classmethod` again

The usual way to define custom exceptions is just:

```
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    pass
```

you then raise it with any custom message you want. What is important to note, is that you raise it explicitly wherever you need to. Using a static method (instead of the class method you used) to do it for you is not common and impairs readability. If you really need to save on typing predifined error messages you can either:

- store them as constants/class attributes;
- define them as default value for the constructor.

## On reinventing the wheel

There is a bunch of built-ins that you could use to simplify the reading of your code. For insance `divmod`, `math.copysign` or `zip`. You’re also using two methods for building your string outputs where they very much look alike.

Lastly, `_move` is very unintuitive with its two passes, its `decimal` flag (yes it takes a while to figure out it is both some kind of flag and some values stored) and its `stop` one. The least intuitive thing, however, is how you differentiate things whether you’re adding more or less than a block size on a given axis. That lead to all issues stated above. You should add the decimal parts and then take care of the integral ones using your block approach.

And since you access `self.player_loc[direction]` a lot, you should make it a local variable.

## Proposed improvements

```
from math import copysign
from itertools import count, repeat, izip, chain

class Movement(object):
    """This was built to allow large coordinates to be stored without
    causing any floating point precision errors.
    It is faster than the decimal module, especially with processing
    large amounts of small movements.

    It works by breaking down the coordinates into 'blocks', where each
    new block is the squared amount of the previous one.
    The method is very similar to the base number system, in which a
    block size of 10 will split 235.9 into [5.9, 3, 2].

    A large block size is faster than a small one, though the precision
    will be worse. At 16 digits, Python can't store any more decimals,
    so definitely keep it under that.
    """

    BLOCK_SIZE = 65535

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0, block_size=None):
        """Convert the starting coordinates into the format accepted
        by the class.

        >>> m = Movement('15',
        ...              '-31564.99933425584842',
        ...              '1699446367870005.2')
        >>> m.player_loc
        [[15.0], [-31564.99933425585], [38640.2, 17514, 2485, 6]]

        >>> print m
        (15.0, -31564.9993343, 1699446367870005.2)
        """

        #Set a new block size if needed
        if block_size is not None:
            self.BLOCK_SIZE = block_size

        #Store the initial coordinates
        self.player_loc = [self.calculate(*self._split_decimal_part(i))
                           for i in (x, y, z)]


    def __repr__(self):
        """This needs improving, currently it just converts back to
        the absolute coordinates."""
        return 'Movement{}'.format(self)


    def __str__(self):
        """Return the absolute coordinates."""
        return '({}, {}, {})'.format(*self._convert_to_world())


    def __getitem__(self, i):
        """Return an absolute value for X, Y or Z.

        Parameters:
            i (int): Index of coordinate.
        """
        try:
            return self._convert_to_world()[i]
        except IndexError:
            raise MovementError(MovementError.COORDINATE_INDEX_ERROR)


    def __setitem__(self, i, n):
        """Set an absolute value for X, Y or Z.

        Parameters:
            i (int): Index of coordinate.

            n (int/float/str): New value to set.
        """
        try:
            self.player_loc[i] = self.calculate(*self._split_decimal_part(n))
        except IndexError:
            raise MovementError(MovementError.COORDINATE_INDEX_ERROR)


    @staticmethod
    def _split_decimal_part(n):
        """Split the input into its integral part and its decimal part.

        Parameters:
            n (str/int/float): Integer to convert.

        >>> Movement._split_decimal_part('15.35321')
        (15, 35321)
        """
        n = str(n)
        try:
            integral, decimal = n.split('.')
        except ValueError:
            return int(n), 0
        else:
            return int(integral) if integral else 0, int(decimal) if decimal else 0


    def calculate(self, amount, decimal=0):
        """Convert the coordinate into a block.

        Parameters:
            amount (int/str): Total value without any decimals.

            decimal (int, optional): The decimal value as an integer
                without the leading '0.'.

        >>> Movement().calculate(128)
        [128.0]
        >>> Movement().calculate(128, 5176)
        [128.5176]
        >>> Movement().calculate(4294836224)
        [65534.0, 65534]
        >>> Movement().calculate(4294836225)
        [0.0, 0, 1]
        """
        amount = int(amount)
        multiplier = int(copysign(1, amount))
        amount *= multiplier

        coordinate = []
        while amount >= self.BLOCK_SIZE:
            amount, remainder = divmod(amount, self.BLOCK_SIZE)
            coordinate.append(remainder * multiplier)
        coordinate.append(amount * multiplier)

        decimal = float('0.{}'.format(decimal))
        coordinate[0] += decimal * multiplier

        return coordinate


    def _move(self, direction, amount):
        """Add the coordinate to a block.

        Parameters:
            direction (int): Represents X, Y, or Z as a number.

            amount (int/float): Amount to add or subtract from the
            coordinate.

        >>> m = Movement(135, 426.42, -1499941.5002)
        >>> print m
        (135.0, 426.42, -1499941.5002)

        >>> m.move(100, -5133.100532, 5)
        >>> print m
        (235.0, -4706.680532, -1499936.5002)
        """
        axis = self.player_loc[direction]
        amount_blocks = self.calculate(*self._split_decimal_part(amount))
        overflow = 0

        for amount, base, i in izip(axis, chain(amount_blocks,repeat(0)), count(0)):
            total = amount + base + overflow
            negatif = total < 0
            overflow, remainder = divmod(-total if negatif else total, self.BLOCK_SIZE)
            axis[i] = -remainder if negatif else remainder
            overflow = int(-overflow if negatif else overflow)

        for amount in amount_blocks[i+1:]:
            total = amount + overflow
            negatif = total < 0
            overflow, remainder = divmod(-total if negatif else total, self.BLOCK_SIZE)
            axis.append(-remainder if negatif else remainder)
            overflow = -overflow if negatif else overflow

        negatif = overflow < 0
        overflow = -overflow if negatif else overflow
        while overflow > 0:
            overflow, remainder = divmod(overflow, self.BLOCK_SIZE)
            axis.append(-remainder if negatif else remainder)


    def move(self, x, y, z):
        """Update the coordinates with a new relative location."""
        for i, amount in enumerate((x, y, z)):
            if amount:
                self._move(i, amount)


    def _convert_to_world(self):
        """Convert the blocks into absolute coordinates as a string."""

        #Convert coordinates back to numbers, without using floats
        coordinates = [sum(int(amount) * self.BLOCK_SIZE**i
                           for i, amount in enumerate(coordinate))
                       for coordinate in self.player_loc]

        #Add the decimal points as strings
        coordinates = ['{}.{}'.format(coord, str(location[0]).split('.')[1])
                       for coord, location in zip(coordinates, self.player_loc)]

        #Fix for numbers between -1 and 0
        for i, location in enumerate(self.player_loc):
            if len(location) == 1 and (-1 < location[0] < 0):
                coordinates[i] = '-' + coordinates[i]
        return coordinates


class MovementError(Exception):
    """Custom movement exceptions."""
    COORDINATE_INDEX_ERROR = 'coordinate index out of range'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

## A word on accuracy and speed

Since you have specific needs as regard to speed and accuracy, you may find that writing functions to factorize some code may be slower than explicitly writing the same kind of call. That's why I didn't try to remove redundancy in `_move`.

You may still have room for improvement though: `__getitem__` does not need to compute all 3 axis before returning the required one; `_convert_to_world` can iterate over `self.player_loc` one less time using:

```
coordinates = [str(sum(int(amount) * self.BLOCK_SIZE**i
                   for i, amount in enumerate(coordinate)))
               + '.' + str(coordinate[0]).split('.')[1]
               for coordinate in self.player_loc]
```

In the end it's up to your requirements that you can consider readability and maintenance improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll reply to a few of the more basic points. Good idea with the decimals, I hadn't noticed I only used them together haha. And with '@classmethod', I tend to throw it in if `__init__` isn't needed, but it's usually an afterthought, so at least now I have a better idea of how/when to use it. I've never used `divmod` or  `math.copysign` but looking at your code they seem so much nicer than my version, and I was thinking `zip` would run a lot slower. As to `'{}.{}'.format()`, I'd done a quick test and found that `x+'.'+x` ran so much faster, even if it does look worse.

Comment: @Peter found some time to edit in the changes for `_move`. As far as performances are concerned, I didn't test anything. Neither speed, nor float accuracy. So some advices might not suit you, indeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I'll go over everything you've done tonight or tomorrow when I get time. Like I'd mentioned in the post, as long as there's enough precision for smooth movement, accuracy isn't really important, since you wouldn't notice slight errors anyway. As long as something is relatively similar speed wise, that's fine (like a couple of function calls in `_move` is ok, just not hundreds), I'm mainly just being overly cautious based on previous experience aha.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the wait, I'm currently trying out the code and attempting to fix a bug with your overflow part. For example, `Movement('124151.4',0,0).move('11286.45',0,0)` comes out with `Movement(4294906127.85, 0.0, 0.0)`, It should be `[4367.85, 2]` but your code results in `[4367.85, 1, 1]`, I know why it's doing that part, just need to figure out why it's happening when it shouldn't be :P

Comment: I couldn't figure out the fix, so I turned it into a very simple version based on yours that works correctly as far as I can tell - http://pastebin.com/s0Zh0LJ0

Comment: @Peter The issue is because I accounted for `amount_blocks` being greater (more elements) than `axis` with `for amount in amount_block[i+1:]` but not the other way around. I will edit shortly to handle that

Comment: One question actually, how can you tell when setting something as a local variable will edit the original value, or only the local variable? It seemed to work at the end when I did `amount = remainder` too, but it seemed a bit sketchy so I changed it back to `self.player_loc[direction][i] = remainder` to be safe, since I thought that behaviour only applied to dictionaries.

Comment: @Peter Ok, it should be fixed now. As for “editing” an object or a container through an alias, it's rather easy. When you use methods that mutate an object, all of its references are updated as well since they refer to the same object. When you assign to a previously used variable, you are removing that reference and thus not touching the previous object. `axis[i] = some_value` is actualy `axis.__setitem__(i,some_value)` which mutates `axis` in place, thus updating `self.player_loc[direction]` since they refer to the same thing.

Comment: Ah nice, thanks. Also, it seemed to work with `for amount in axis` if I updated `amount`, but I can't get that behaviour happening anywhere else, is that something that should also mutate in place or not?

Comment: http://gestaltrevision.be/wiki/python/aliases might be useful to you.